# Including assemblies with DLL in Microsoft Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

I created a DLL that references the `System.IO.Ports` assembly, but If I use that DLL in another project it gives me the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptions 'could not load file or assembly System.IO.Ports, Version = 7.0.0.0, sometoken here xxxxx' the system cannot find the file specified.

If this assembly is included in the DLL, why is it asking for it when I use the DLL from another application? Do I need to modify a property in Visual Studio, so this doesn't happen?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a .NET (Core) 7 assembly in a .NET Framework project. That's not possible. You can only share assemblies between .NET Core and .NET Framework if they target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The project is a .NET Core project.  Shouldn't that work?